# screenrc - blinking hardstatus from hell

Tags: gnu-screen, screenrc

I copied a few lines from somewhere into my .screenrc to give me an informative hardstatus line:

```
# An alternative hardstatus to display a bar at the bottom listing the
# windownames and highlighting the current windowname in blue. (This is only
# enabled if there is no hardstatus setting for your terminal)
hardstatus alwayslastline "%{.bW}%-w%{.rW}%n %t%{-}%+w %=%{..G} %H %{..Y} %m/%d %C%a "
```

As per the screen [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#String-Escapes), the 'blinking' color modifier is B. Yet the hardstatus line has NO B's anywhere... and it still blinks! It's driving me nuts. I've looked at other screenrc's, asked coworkers, removed tokens left and right from this status line, but nothing will stop it blinking.

How can I get the nice red-on-blue status line, *without* blinking? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't blink for me. (screen 4.0.3)

Comment: Do you have anything else in your .screenrc that would influence blinking?

Answer (score 0):

I happened to find this phenomena.
It's a typical compound display question. In my enviornment, I use screen hardstatus config similar to yours, and use Xshell as terminal tool. I use linux in Xshell, this phenomena occurs. If I change to xterm, it disappears definitely.
So, try to change your Xshell config.